# call_once implementation through double checked locking pattern

Tags: c++, qt, boost, poco-libraries

How boost::call_once is implemented ?

Does this one use the double checked locking pattern ?

Is there any equivalent implementation in Qt or POCO library ?

Comment: You know the 'double checked locking pattern' is no good?

Comment: I would not POCO threads

Comment: The problem is that I need to implement a singleton pattern in a multi threaded environment. I did some analysis on double checked locking pattern(and its inefficiency) and boost call_once. I am not supposed to use boost library. So I need an implementation.

Comment: My compiler does not support std::call_once.

Comment: static Singleton instance - before main?

Comment: The problem with double-checked locking is not that it's inefficient, it's that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this older question..
After 4 years, it is probably no longer interesting for your case but I believe a sample implementation may still have some value.

contrary to the claim in the comments section that DCLP is broken, this is no longer true in C++11 since it provides the necessary atomic types, operations and memory barriers.

This is is a minimal implementation, not necessarily the `boost` implementation. Exception behavior is ignored.
The argument function of `my_call_once` is guaranteed to be called no more than once and shared data is properly synchronized between threads.. just like the real thing `std::call_once`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

class my_once_flag {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::atomic<bool> flg{false};

    template<typename Func, typename... Args>
    friend void my_call_once(my_once_flag&, Func&&, Args&&...);
};

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void my_call_once(my_once_flag& flag, Func&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    if (flag.flg.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == false)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck{flag.mtx};

        if (flag.flg.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == true)
            return;

        std::forward<Func>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        flag.flg.store(true, std::memory_order_release);
    }
}

void just_once(int i) { std::cout << "once " << i << std::endl; }

int main()
{
    my_once_flag of;

    std::thread {[&]{ my_call_once(of, just_once, 1); }}.join();
    std::thread {[&]{ my_call_once(of, just_once, 2); }}.join();
}
```